# Selenium & Docker: I can't load custom chrome user profile

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I opened the following issue a cuple days ago but apparently it isn't an issue but my problem persist. I hope someone can help me to understand what is wrong :D

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/issues/790

Resume:

I'm trying to run a test using selenium + javascript in a docker machine.
The test run ok but I can't load the user profile adding:

`` options.addArguments(`user-data-dir=/miCustomProfilePath`); ``

If I execute my test using the image node-chrome-debug I can check in the configuration that always the path is something like:

`/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.iBLIx2/Default`

Docker compose:

`version: "2"
services:
  selenium-hub:
    image: selenium/hub:latest
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
  chrome:
    image: selenium/node-chrome-debug:latest
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "5900:5900"
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
      - /Users/osvaldo/profiles/custom_profile:/home/seluser/custom_profile
    environment:
      - HUB_HOST=selenium-hub
      - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=5
      - NODE_MAX_SESSION=5`

Javascript code:

```
    let options = new chrome.Options();
    options.addArguments(`user-data-dir=/home/seluser/custom_profile`);

    driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .setChromeOptions(options)
        .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
        .build();
```

I tried generate the profile from the console and running a test with a new user-data-dir.
Same issue on Debian and Mac.
Have you an idea where is the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution for this problem? I also faced this problem and would like to know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that we should set the capabilities of goog:chromeOptions instead of chromeOptions. It should be done automatically if we have the correct binding. I changed my selenium version to 3.14 and it sets the capabilities to goog:chromeOptions and it loads my custom chrome profile

I found it from this link
https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/issues/201